# Open in Windows Explorer doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-server, webdav, windows-xp, ie8

Here are my environment settings:

OS: Windows XP 2002
IE: 8 32 bit
SharePoint Site Version: 2013
Site permissions: Contribute
Document library permission: Contribute
Site type: Intranet
Site protocol: https over ssl (wildcard certificate) port 443

We recently migrated to SharePoint 2013 from MOSS 2007. Users with Windows 7 client machines are having no issues accessing the site.

Web Client service has been started in services.msc.

When user tries to access the wedav link they are encountered with

> Cannot find file" " Make sure the path or Internet address is correct

Please help.

Comment: With IE8 I **always** try _compatability view_ when something doesn't work that should -- have you tried that yet? Short of that, may be time to upgrade those workstation OSs? I don't remember IE8 playing nicely with any incarnation of SP2013 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the method described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b6a2dc07-d922-4346-8e0a-4f049da9a6b9/share-point-2007-how-do-i-solve-this-error-messages).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178000/EN-US

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7405a6a7-ea6b-43d9-9b79-60adc9a4eb0d/explorer-view-giving-error-in-document-library-in-moss-2007